# How can I escape the string in breadcrumbs gem "crummy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called "crummy" (https://github.com/zachinglis/crummy)

**Controller**

```
add_crumb @user.nickname
```

note: Assuming `@user.nickname="<h1>John"`, here

**View**

```
<%= render_crumbs :separator => '/', :renderer => Crummy::MyRenderer.new %>
```

When it outputs breadcrumbs, it contains `<h1>` tag in it.
How can I escape this???

I tried to change the line in controller to this.

```
add_crumb h(@user.nickname)
```

But it returns error :(

Comment: did you try `.html_safe` on the whole string?

Comment: @phoet where at? In view just like this? <%= render_crumbs :separator => '/', :renderer => Crummy::MyRenderer.new.html_safe %>

Comment: no, the WHOLE string, `render_crumbs(:separator => '/', :renderer => Crummy::MyRenderer.new).html_safe`

Comment: @phoet I tried that but it outputs the same result. It's because that `html_safe` won't replace `tags`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Ruby builtin class like `CGI::escapeHTML(@user.nickname)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you show me how to code it in my Controller?

Comment: this is a bad idea. it circumvents the internal cross-site-scripting-protection. using `html_safe` or `raw` is the recommended way in rails.

Comment: @phoet In this situation, I definitely have to do something in controller when adding `@user.nickname` to crumb list. Because whole crumb list has hyperlinks in it so that I cannot escape whole strings there.

Comment: It's a horrible idea, but the dude asked a question. No Idea why he wants it there and only half an h1 too, you should style the crumbs rather then put style into the output'd data.

Comment: @MKK almost to the point where if crumbs won't let you style or add css, find another one, or forgo breadcrumbs... it is 2013 :-) My lame humour aside, if it's not easy to style, then onto the next, is what I'd do.

Comment: @pjammer is there any other awesome gem just like crummy? and another question. Should I just define validation for nickname not to have markup in it?

Comment: yes. as Phoet said. never never never trust user data.  Then barely trust your own data after that. There are some real dirtbag scum out there, and yes if your app even gets a sniff of fame, this dirtbag will find it and exploit. usually just for fun. It's holes like this that dirtbags prey on. So only allow letters and numbers if you really need to.